# How to measure the similarity between the slopes of two lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Let assume that we have 3 lines A(slope=-1), B(slope=-0.9), and C(slope=-0.7). We say that line A is more similar to B than C (similar by their slopes). Is there a well-formed formula to measure such a similarity between the slopes of two lines?  I can figure it out in an if-else algorithm, but for the positive slope values I get the wrong answer.

Comment: You mean something else than take the two slopes and make a subtraction ?

Comment: If both of the other lines are on the same side, this sounds fairly easy: A is closer to B than A is to C. But things already become more difficult if the sides are opposite: If you compare B to A and C, which one is closer? Do you use the slope as given, or rather the angle? Here you have to be specific as to what you want. Then you can most likely compute the difference in the unit of your choice, take the absolute value and use that as a measure of similarity.